# set it to null and get variable data in just one line

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var checkActiveBrand = $(".brand__title").attr("data-brand-title");
```

I have this variable to get my `.brand__title` data but I also want to check if it was empty or not , but I don't want to use `if` to check it.

```
if(!checkActiveBrand){
 checkActiveBrand = null;
}
```

I don't want to use this, I want a single line to set it all up and, if not,  return `null` without using `if` statement. Is there a way? cause I have a lot of data to check, it will be messy if I set all and check it one by one.

Comment: I think you would love C#'s `??` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortest one would be this with inline `||` and you can make use of `.data()` method:

```js
var checkActiveBrand = $(".brand__title").data("brandTitle") || null;

console.log(checkActiveBrand);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='brand__title' data-brand-title=''>Data brand title attr is "".</div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
checkActiveBrand = (checkActiveBrand) ? checkActiveBrand : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator which is part of Javascript. You include the condition you want to test, followed by a `?`, followed by the value if true,`:`, value if false.

```
var checkActiveBrand = $(".brand__title").attr("data-brand-title") ? $(".brand__title").attr("data-brand-title") : null;
```